# How to resolve assembly name / namespace conflict issue with in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application that has a assembly name / namespace conflict with another class library application that Im referencing inside the console application.

To resolve the namespace conflict, in my Main method (entry point) I call the class library with the use of an alias.  However I'm still getting an error saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
> Unknown Module. Could not load type 'OSEStorage.StorageDB' from
> assembly 'OSEStorage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'.

I'm using .net 4.8 and using visual studio 2017.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you mean you have two(or more) libraries with same binary name and namespaces/classes?

Comment: If your namespace is the same as the library just change the name of the namespace. If you have 2 libraries you have to make sure both libraries are not in the same folder. This will result in conflicts. Even better is to rebuild 1 of the libraries with a different name.